# Numerically solve an equation using Python

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving

How could I (numerically) solve this equation for $\alpha$ given $x_i$ (these are known) ?

$\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{x_i-\alpha} = \frac{2N}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\alpha)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{(x_i-\alpha)}$

In fact my aim is to solve the following system for $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$\beta = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\alpha)^2}{2N}} (1)$

$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{x_i-\alpha} = \frac{1}{\beta^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\alpha) (2)$

Thus the very first equation is obtained where I put (1) in (2).

Equations (1) and (2) are obtained while solving for the maximum likelihood estimators the following distribution (special case of Weibull):
$f(x) = \frac{x_i-\alpha}{\beta^2}e^{-\frac{(x_i-\alpha)^2}{2\beta^2}}$

Comment: If you were given this as an assignment, then you were also given the tools neccessary to solve it. So what are your difficulties exactly?

Comment: That's not an assignment and that's why I have no idea to solve it.

Comment: i have updated the very first post.

Comment: I see. How large is $N$? It would make sense to give the value of $N$ at least, or the range of possible values. If $N$ is small, this is one case, and if $N$ is very large, this is quite another case

Comment: There was no square in (2), so now my first post is correct. How would you solve it?

Comment: To be more accurate, equations (1) and (2) are obtained while searching for a maximum likelihood estimator of a shifted Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: This is a problem with scores of solutions. Here is why. Give the name $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$, resp to the LHS and RHS. The curve of $f$ has N vertical asymptotes (thus $N+1$ branches) and the horizontal axis as an asymptote. The curve of $g$ has only one branch and has as well the $\alpha$ axis as horizontal asymptote. Thus the two curves intersect at least $N-1$ times in intervals $[ x_i,x_{i+1} ]$. Then  applying Newton iterations with a seed in these intervals (not forgetting intervals $(-\infty, x_1)$ and $(x_N,+\infty)$) is likely to give you "most" solutions.

Comment: As it is a special case of a Weibull distribution, is it the classical method to solve it?

Comment: If you are looking for a single solution as I understand, I think you have to add supplementary constraints...

Comment: As my $x_i$ correspond to pixel's intensity values, they range from 0 to 255.